# Linking from mobile site to a specific product in the amazon app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, url

So I'm attempting to link from my mobile site into a specific item in Amazon's app. Using a try/catch in my js, if they do not have the app it will catch the redirect and send them to the webpage instead. I've been struggling to find the URL scheme for the amazon app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link. It lists how to connect for an android device.

https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/community/post/Tx3A1TVL67TB24B/Linking-To-the-Amazon-Appstore-for-Android

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

On android Amazon uses this scheme to launch the app `amzn://apps/android?`

[image: amzn info]

FULL DOCUMENTATION: https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx3A1TVL67TB24B/Linking-To-the-Amazon-Appstore-for-Android

BUT I don't think there would be anyway to access the device with javascript to detect if the app is installed. This is for security reasons...

Comment: I saw the android scheme, however since it's a mobile site and not an app I need something that I can target all phones with (iOS and Android) with either the same or 2 seperate redirect commands. Any ideas?

Comment: Also @Sam Battat, I dont think I would need to check if the app is installed with a try/catch. If the try doesnt work then it will go to catch and I'll just send them to the webpage on their browser